# Renaming filename with article name before uploading

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename, php-5.5

I would like to know if its possible to add title of the article to file name when uploading it ?

Example:
I am uploading files with simple code

```
    $directory = '../images/adds/';
    $temp_file = $directory . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $temp_file)) {
        echo "<p style='color:#1dff03;'>file uploaded.</p>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p style='color:#f00;'>File cant be uploaded.</p>";
    }
```

I am saving file name in database with title : my-article-name-filename.png
but cant upload to server with article title, is it possible to get some help?

Comment: they are not same questions to me, other two questions are about random naming files but mine is renaming file name with article name, I am not a professinal coder, sorry if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put your desired file name in the `$temp_file` variable. In the following example I used the `$new_name` variable in the first line to define it:

```
$new_name='my-article-filename.png';

$directory = '../images/adds/';
$temp_file = $directory . $new_name;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $temp_file)) {
    echo "<p style='color:#1dff03;'>file uploaded.</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<p style='color:#f00;'>File cant be uploaded.</p>";
}
```

Comment: awesome friend thank you very much.